# checking input field value from backend array that present or not in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i want something like this, that i have list of some of the post codes of UK, and i want to save them in array, and when a user enter a post code from array it shows correct and if it is not present in the array it should show wrong, basically i want to do something post code checker. i know the code is not valid it's just  a demo because i am very weak with arrays, so please can you help me.
thanks

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="z()"><span id="err"></span>

<script>
function z()
{
var a=document.getElementById("test");
if((a.value=="an apple")||(a.value=="SW6"))
{
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'correct';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'wrong';

}

}
</script>
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```js
const postcodes = ["SW6"];

// This will compare the strings and return true
//if they have the same base letters
let ciEquals = (a, b) => {
  let opts = { sensitivity: "base" };
  return a.localeCompare(b, undefined, opts) === 0;
};

let isValid = value => {
  for (let postcode of postcodes) {
    if (ciEquals(postcode, value)) return true;
  }
  return false;
};

document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var value = document.getElementById("test").value;
  if (!value) return;
  document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = isValid(value) ?
    "correct" :
    "wrong";
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="test" />
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" />
<span id="err"></span>
```

If you type `SW6` you'll see "correct"

Comment: also i want the lowercase should also be right, like sw6 or Sw6 or sW6, what will be the process.please can you help
 thanks

Comment: @MuhammadYasirAsif, I've updated my answer, let me know if you have any question about the code above. It's a little more complex, but I've tried to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: @Luise Ramalho that is great work by you thanks very much, yahooo that solves my problem.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! :)